JOLT config fix
I've a JSON like this:
{
  "result": {
    "Ads": [
      {
        "Id": 16198570913,
        "AdGroupId": 5453796748,
        "Status": "ACCEPTED",
        "CpmBannerAdBuilderAd": {
          "TurboPageId": 533,
          "TurboPageModeration": null,
          "Creative": {
            "CreativeId": 113152230434,
            "ThumbnailUrl": "/8383ee33-b38f-44b9-af79-1ea48835892d/orig",
            "PreviewUrl": "/1131522304/preview"
          },
          "ErirAdDescription": null,
          "AutogeneratedErirAdDescription": null
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": 16198570914,
        "CampaignId": 111544648,
        "AdGroupId": 5453796748,
        "Status": "ACCEPTED",
        "CpmVideoAdBuilderAd": {
          "Creative": {
            "CreativeId": 241131522305,
            "ThumbnailUrl": "/56360bcb-b65f-484c-8bdb-0e9e8006f739/orig",
            "PreviewUrl": "1131522305/preview"
          },
          "ErirAdDescription": null,
          "AutogeneratedErirAdDescription": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

I want to go through result and grab Ads array with all elements but with certain keys. I need AdGroupId and also CpmBannerAdBuilderAd or CpmVideoAdBuilderAd with almost all things inside it: inside Creative i need only CreativeId. Other keys not inside Creative I should include to result. But keys that are nulls I should remove from result json. So I expect to get this result:
{
  "Ads": [
    {
      "AdGroupId": 5453796748,
      "CpmBannerAdBuilderAd": {
        "TurboPageId": 533,
        "Creative": {
          "CreativeId": 113152230434
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "AdGroupId": 5453796748,
      "CpmBannerAdBuilderAd": {
        "Creative": {
          "CreativeId": 241131522305
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

My attempt was:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "result": {
        "Ads": {
          "*": {
            "AdGroupId": "[&1].AdGroupId",
            "CpmBannerAdBuilderAd|CpmVideoAdBuilderAd": "[&1].CpmBannerAdBuilderAd" //wrong thing
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "Ads[]"
    }
  }
]

But I don't understand how to proper make this string "CpmBannerAdBuilderAd|CpmVideoAdBuilderAd": "[&1].CpmBannerAdBuilderAd"  Because I hardcoded it to always be as CpmBannerAdBuilderAd, but it should be CpmBannerAdBuilderAd or CpmVideoAdBuilderAd depends on key value. How can I fix it? Also I need to fix Creative key to grab only CreativeId.
UPD
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "AdGroupId": "&2[&1].&",
            "Cpm*|Cpc*": {
              "*": "&3[&2].&",
              "Creative": {
                "CreativeId": "&4[&3].&2.&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]


You can use the following single shift transformation spec :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "AdGroupId": "&2[&1].&",
            "Cpm*": {
              "TurboPageId": "&3[&2].&1.&",
              "Creative": {
                "CreativeId": "&4[&3].&2.&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

where

* represents zero, one, or multiple characters, above Cpm*  means all keys starting with Cpm as an example
& wildcard is a replicator for the keys from any level

Edit : Rather you can prefer using the following transformation considering the case related to the unwanted null values :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "Cpm*": {
              "~*": "Null"//if these attibutes don't exist or are null, then make them literal "Null"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "AdGroupId": "&2[&1].&",
            "Cpm*": {
              "*": {
                "*": { "@1": "&5[&4].&3.&2" },
                "Null": { "": "" }//Make the pairs to be disaapeared for those with "Null" literal values 
              },
              "Creative": {
                "CreativeId": "&4[&3].&2.&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Thanks! You add field "TurboPageId": "&3[&2].&1.&", but sometimes this field is also can be null and I want to not display this key if it's null. So inside "Cpm*|Cpc*": (without Creative key) I want to  get all keys that are not null.

I fixed it by myself with recursivelySquashNulls but maybe it can be done without it? But also something wrong in my last attempt, because TurboPageId now is up by one level in json structure (not inside creative as it should be)

Excuse me @MarkAvreliy that I didn't notice the cases with null values, I've just fixed the answer.
